# Google Apps Script Failed

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

A couple years back, I installed a script called "Monthly Stats for Gmail" from another gmail user. It would give me my own analytics on when I would send, receive, and who I would send and receive email from.  I am now getting this error email every day at the same time 1:13AM, seemingly arbitrary time. I have combed thru the Google Apps Scripts documentation as well as the links given in the email. Is there a way to "uninstall" time based triggers when I was not the originator or author? I am fairly frustrated and would appreciate your help. I am getting this error in the form of an email below. Thx.[google script error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZx6O.png)

Comment: You should be able to go to the Script Editor Edit/current project triggers or Edit/all your triggers.  From there you can disable them.

Comment: You can also go into your account and look at the apps that you have given run permissions to.  [https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps)

Comment: @Cooper Have a couple questions. How can I access those triggers when the script was created by another google user?  Can I access a list of scripts other than what is located thru an existing Google sheet?

Comment: @SandyGood Sandy, that list doesn't include this particular script. Do you know how to get to timebased triggers?

Comment: I'm not sure what else you can do.  Do you still have that email?  Still in trash? It had a link in it.

Comment: @SandyGood Yes. Link leads to 403 error: Forbidden. any work around?

Comment: I don't know.  You could try asking the Apps Script Community [Link](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)